# Proof that $\frac{d}{dt} \log |A(t)| = \text{Tr}\left[A(t)^{-1} \frac{d}{dt} A \right]$

Tags: linear-algebra

For a symmetric $n\times n$  matrix $A(t)$ that depends on the variable $t$, I want to prove that
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \log |A(t)| = \text{Tr}\left[A(t)^{-1} \frac{d}{dt} A(t) \right].
$$

Here, $|A|$ denotes the determinant of $A$ and $\text{Tr}[X]$ denotes the trace of $X$. How can I prove this equality?

---

The reason I ask this question: The equality is presented in equation C.22 of Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning of C. Bishop and the proof is left "as an exercise to the reader".

---

My attempt so far (to not clutter the notation, I leave out the dependency on $t$):

We know that $|A|=\prod_{i=1}^n \lambda_i$, where $\lambda_i$ denotes the $i$-th eigenvalue.
Hence, we can write
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \log|A|
=\frac{d}{dt}\log\prod_{i=1}^n\lambda_i
=\frac{d}{dt}\sum_{i=1}^n\log(\lambda_i)
=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{d}{dt}\log(\lambda_i)
=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\lambda_i} \frac{d}{dt}\lambda_i.
$$

The textbook further suggests to make use of the equalities
$$ 
A = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i u_i u_i^T 
\quad \text{and} \quad 
A^{-1} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\lambda_i} u_i u_i^T, 
$$
where $u_i$ denotes the $i$-th eigenvector.

I do not know how to proceed from here. I also do not know if this is going into the right direction.

Comment: is there some assumption that the determinant of $A(t)$ is positive?

Comment: @angryavian I agree, otherwise $\log(|A(t)|)$ could be ill-defined.

Comment: @angryavian Good point. In the appendix (where this equality is stated), it is not mentioned whether the determinant of $A(t)$ is positive. But I guess it has to be positive, otherwise it doesn't work. When they make use of the equality in the textbook itself, it seems that $A(t)$ is positive definite, so then the determinant should be positive as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided the problem is well-defined, i.e. matrix is diagonalizable, non-singular and determinant is positive, one should be able to use the orthonormality of eigenvectors, i.e.

$$
\mathbf{u}^T_i.\mathbf{u}_j=\sum_s u^\left(s\right)_i u^{\left(s\right)}_j=
\begin{cases}
1,\quad i=j \\
0,\quad otherwise
\end{cases}
$$

Where sum over $\dots^{\left(s\right)}$ is over individual components of the eigen-vectors.

Now:

$$
\begin{align}
\mbox{Tr}\left(\mathbf{A^{-1}}.\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{A}\right)=&\mbox{Tr}\left(\left[\sum_i \mathbf{u}_i.\frac{1}{\lambda_i}.\mathbf{u}_i^T\right]\:\cdot\:\frac{d}{dt}\left[\sum_j \mathbf{u}_j .\lambda_j.\mathbf{u}_j^T\right]\right) \\
=&\sum_{sp}\sum_{ij}u^{(s)}_i\lambda_i^{-1}u^{(p)}_i\cdot\left(\frac{du^{(p)}_j}{dt}\lambda_ju^{(s)}_j+u^{(p)}_j\frac{d\lambda_j}{dt} u^{(s)}_j+u^{(p)}_j \lambda_j \frac{du^{(s)}_j}{dt}\right)\\
=&\sum_i \frac{1}{\lambda_i}\cdot\frac{d\lambda_i}{dt}+\sum_p\sum_i u^{(p)}_i\frac{du^{(p)}_i}{dt}+\sum_s\sum_i u^{(s)}_i\frac{du^{(s)}_i}{dt}\\
=&\sum_i \frac{1}{\lambda_i}\cdot\frac{d\lambda_i}{dt}+2\sum_s\sum_i u^{(s)}_i\frac{du^{(s)}_i}{dt}\\
=&\sum_i \frac{1}{\lambda_i}\cdot\frac{d\lambda_i}{dt}+\frac{d}{dt}\sum_s\sum_i u^{(s)}_i u^{(s)}_i \\
=&\sum_i \frac{1}{\lambda_i}\cdot\frac{d\lambda_i}{dt}
\end{align} 
$$

Since

$$
\sum_i \sum_s u^{(s)}_i u^{(s)}_i = \sum_i 1=\mbox{number of components}=\mbox{const}
$$

Which, I think, was what you were after

Comment: In the last sentence, you mean $\sum_i \sum_s u_i^s u_i^s = \sum_i 1$? (note the $\sum_s$)

Comment: Very nice proof! Thanks!

Comment: @EdG. Glad it helps. Regarding the earlier comment. Yes, you are correct :-)

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\Tr}{\mathrm{Tr}}$
$\newcommand{\adj}{\mathrm{adj}}$

In fact, the equality holds as long as $\det(A(t)) > 0$ (the symmetry condition is not needed).

The key identity we need is that for any $A(t)$ ($\det(A(t))$ may equal to $0$):
\begin{align*}
\frac{d(\det(A(t)))}{dt} = \sum_{i = 1}^n\sum_{j = 1}^n \frac{d a_{ij}(t)}{dt}A_{ij}(t) = \Tr\left(\frac{d(A(t))}{dt}\mathrm{adj}(A(t))\right), \tag{1}
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
\adj(A(t)) = \begin{pmatrix} A_{11}(t) & A_{21}(t) & \cdots & A_{n1}(t) \\
A_{12}(t) & A_{22}(t) & \cdots & A_{n2}(t) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
A_{1n}(t) & A_{2n}(t) & \cdots & A_{nn}(t)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
is the adjugate matrix of $A(t)$ thus it satisfies
\begin{align*}
A(t)\adj(A(t)) = \det(A(t))I_{(n)}.
\end{align*}

When $\det(A(t)) > 0$ hence $A(t)$ is invertible, $\adj(A(t)) = \det(A(t))A(t)^{-1}$, whence by the chain rule we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{d\log(\det(A(t)))}{dt} &= \frac{1}{\det(A(t))}\frac{d(\det(A(t)))}{dt}
= \frac{1}{\det(A(t))}\Tr\left(\frac{d(A(t))}{dt}\mathrm{adj}(A(t))\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{\det(A(t))}\Tr\left(\frac{d(A(t))}{dt}\det(A(t))A(t)^{-1}\right) 
 = \Tr\left(\frac{d(A(t))}{dt}A(t)^{-1}\right).
\end{align*}

The proof of the first equality in $(1)$ is subtle and quite lengthy. If you are interested, I may post it as an appendix.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your proof (+1)! Am I correct in saying that following (the proof of) Jacobi's formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula), I should be able to prove the "key identify" in (1)? If so, then there is no need to add it here as an appendix :)

Comment: @EdG Yes, correct! In fact, I do not know (1) has a big name associated with it. I learned it from a linear algebra exercise.

Comment: Completely forgot about (1). Thanks Zhanxiong. @EdG, here's a proof of (1) using Levi-Civita symbols if you want https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/i-cant-verify-a-relationship-between-cofactor-and-determinant.970419/#post-6165630

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that there is $B(t)$ such that
$$ A(t)=e^{B(t)}. $$
Then
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\log |A(t)|=\frac{d}{dt}\log |e^{B(t)}|=\frac{d}{dt}\log e^{\text{Tr}B(t)}=\frac{d}{dt}\text{Tr}B(t). $$
On the other hand,
$$ \text{Tr}\left[A(t)^{-1} \frac{d}{dt} A(t) \right]=\text{Tr}\bigg[e^{-B(t)}e^{B(t)}B'(t)\bigg]=\text{Tr}B'(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\text{Tr}B(t). $$
So
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\log |A(t)|=\text{Tr}\left[A(t)^{-1} \frac{d}{dt} A(t) \right].$$

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt}\text{Tr}B(t)=\text{Tr}B'(t)$ is clearly true by linearity of $Tr$. See my answer you need to use $tr(RS)=tr(SR)$ to say that $\frac{d({\rm tr}\log A)}{dt} = \operatorname{tr}\left(A^{-1}\frac{dA}{dt}\right)$ because $A(t),A(t+h),A'(t)$ don't commute

Comment: You are right, hank you

Answer (score 1):

Nicholas Higham published a [wonderful paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/130920137) on the Unwinding Function
$$\eqalign{
{\cal U}(z) &= \frac{z-\log(e^z)}{2\pi i} 
  = \left\lceil\frac{Im(z)-\pi}{2\pi}\right\rceil \;\in\;{\mathbb Z} \\
}$$
Using this function one can write the following *identity*
$$\eqalign{
\log\det A
 &= {\rm tr}\log A - 2\pi i\cdot {\cal U}({\rm tr}\log A) \\
 &= {\rm tr}\log A - 2n\pi i \\
}$$
One of the many interesting properties of the unwinding function is that its derivative is zero, which leads directly to your formula, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
\frac{d(\log\det A)}{dt}
 &= \frac{d({\rm tr}\log A)}{dt} \\
 &= \operatorname{tr}\left(A^{-1}\frac{dA}{dt}\right) \\
}$$
The final equality follows from the identity
$$\eqalign{
\frac{d({\rm tr}(f(A)))}{dt}
 &= \operatorname{tr}\left(f'(A)\cdot\frac{dA}{dt}\right) \\
}$$
where $f$ is any *analytic* function and $f'$ is its derivative.

Comment: Thank you for your original view on this (+1). My problem is that I do not immediately see how the unwinding function leads to the identity $\log\det A
 = {\rm tr}\log A - 2\pi i\cdot {\cal U}({\rm tr}\log A)$. To me, it seems that you use $z={\rm tr}\log A$ and $e^z=\det A$, but I do not immediately see why that would be correct.

Comment: Oh wait, I see that $z={\rm tr}\log A$ and $e^z=\det A$ directly follow from Jacobi's formula.

Comment: @greg See my answer you need to use $tr(BC)=tr(CB)$ to say that $\frac{d({\rm tr}\log A)}{dt} = \operatorname{tr}\left(A^{-1}\frac{dA}{dt}\right)$ because $A(t),A(t+h),A'(t)$ don't commute

Answer (score 0):

From $A(t)$ diagonalizable and $tr(BC)=tr(CB)$ we have $\log \det A(t)=tr \log A(t)$.

Next, $(A(t)^n)'=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} A^k A'(t)A^{n-1-k}$ gives that for $f(z)=\sum_{n\ge 0} c_n z^n$ analytic on a disk containing $\|A(t)\|$ then $$tr(f(A(t)))'=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} tr(A^k A'(t)A^{n-1-k})=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} tr(A^{n-1}A'(t))$$ $$=tr( f'(A(t)) A'(t))$$
$f(z)=\log z$ is not analytic on such a disk, but by analytic continuation in $s$ of $tr(f(I+s(A(t)-I)))'$ it will still hold, ie. $$tr(\log(A(t)))' = tr(A(t)^{-1}A'(t))$$

No need that the eigenvalues of $A(t)$ are positive, just that $A(t)$ is differentiable, $\det(A(t))\ne 0$ and our choice of $tr \log A(t)$ is continuous in $t$.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps my lack of knowledge, but I am already lost after your first sentence. I do not see why the fact that $A(t)$ is diagonalizable and $tr(BC)=tr(CB)$ leads to $\log\det A(t)=tr \log A(t)$.

Comment: $tr(\log(P DP^{-1}))= tr(\log(D))=\sum \log D_{ii}$ and $\log \det PDP^{-1}=\log \det D=\log \prod D_{ii}$, both are equal up to $2ik\pi$, if we choose the $2ik\pi$ such that the functions of $t$ are continuous then that constant will disappear when differentiating